# Criação de Trigger Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Estou criando um trigger para criar uma cópia dos dados alterados na tabela.
Porém apresenta um erro.

```
USE [BANCO1]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[BANCO1]    Script Date: 08/07/2015 14:13:34 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[BANCO1]
  ON [dbo].[TABLE1]
  AFTER  UPDATE
AS


  BEGIN
    DECLARE
    @NOSSONRO   VARCHAR(15) 
    SELECT @NOSSONRO = E1_NUMBCO FROM UPDATED
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE TABLE1 SET E1_NOSNRO = @NOSSONRO  WHERE  E1_NOSNRO='' AND E1_NUMBCO=@NOSSONRO


  END
```

Answer (score 0):

A forma como o SQL Server manipula os eventos que acionam gatilhos (*trigger*) pode se transformar em verdadeira armadilha para quem programa o procedimento de gatilho e desconhece os detalhes específicos do SQL Server, pois enquanto vários gerenciadores de banco de dados acionam o gatilho uma vez para cada linha (*for each row*), no SQL Server o gatilho é acionado uma vez para cada instrução DML (DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE).

```
-- código #1
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[BANCO1]
  ON [dbo].[TABLE1]
  AFTER  UPDATE as
begin
set nocount on;

UPDATE T
  set E1_NOSNRO = I.E1_NOSNRO
  from TABLE1 as T
       inner join INSERTED as I on I.E1_NUMBCO = T.E1_NUMBCO
  where T.E1_NOSNRO = '';

end;
go
```

Sugestão de leitura: [Armadilhas na programação de trigger](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/08/18/armadilhas-na-programacao-de-trigger/).

Answer (score -1):

Entre o **Begin** e o **End** da sua `trigger` utilize o seguinte código:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @NOSSONRO AS VARCHAR(15);

/*Código abaixo obtém o novo E1_NUMBCO, ou seja o valor atualizado. 
Se você quiser pegar o valor antigo do E1_NUMBCO utilize DELETED no lugar do INSERTED*/

SELECT @NOSSONRO = E1_NUMBCO FROM INSERTED;

UPDATE TABLE1 SET E1_NOSNRO = @NOSSONRO  WHERE  E1_NOSNRO='' AND E1_NUMBCO=@NOSSONRO
```

No Sql Server não temos o updated. O updated é tratado como uma exclusão seguido de uma inclusão.